# IntelliJ Idea runs "git log" command in the background causing high CPU usage

Tags: performance, git, cpu-usage, intellij-idea

I have a very large project (~5GB, including `.git`) opened in IntelliJ Idea on MacOS Mojave. I've noticed that CPU usage is quite high while IDE is in the background and doing nothing.

I did some research and noticed that IDE is running following GIT command periodically:

```
/usr/local/bin/git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c diff.renameLimit=1 log -M -m --no-walk=unsorted --stdin --pretty=format:%x01%x01%H%x02%x02%P%x02%x02%ct%x02%x02%cn%x02%x02%ce%x02%x02%an%x02%x02%at%x02%x02%ae%x02%x02%s%x02%x02%b%x02%x02%B%x03%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 --name-status --
```

If I disable "Git" plugin, everything is fine. If I close very large project and keep only small ones, everything is fine too. I guess, `git log` is slow due to the massive size of repository.

Is there any way I can disable this `git log` command or make it run less aggressively without disabling the whole "Git" plugin? I need it sometimes for "Annotate" function only.

Thank you.

Comment: I seem to have a similar problem, although with a much smaller project.

Comment: What git version are you using? Is it one from brew or the one that comes with macos? I've been having similar issues on big sure with latest IntelliJ. The problem for me is that apart from taking a lot of CPU, I can't kill them (kill -9 won't even work on them) so I'm having to do an abrupt restart of the machine.